# How to do create_or_update for elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a simple example:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200'
});

  client.create({ index: 't1', type: 't2', id : id, body: row},function(err,results) {
            callback(err, results )
  })
```

If record is exist, result error: DocumentAlreadyExistsException. How to update record if record exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `client.index` instead of `client.create`. Keep in mind that this will always completely replace your existing document with the given `id`.

Comment: It still throws a DocumentAlreadyExistsException on repeated items even when the id is specified.

Answer (score 10):

In update method have one property - `doc_as_upsert: true`

Try this below code

```
var param = { index: 't1', type: 't2', id : id, body: {doc:row, doc_as_upsert: true
}};

client.update(param,function(err,results) {
            callback(err, results )
})
```

Comment: Does this work for adding a new field to the existing docs? Or do we want to use a different type of query if we are going to add new fields to existing docs that you know the _id?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME;

var elasticSearch = require('elasticsearch');
exports.handler = async(event) => {

//Create elasticSearchClient Object
var elasticSearchClient = new elasticSearch.Client({
secure: true,
hosts: [ ' https://username:password@Endpoint without https://  '],
});

    
//Try pinging Elastic search Client
await elasticSearchClient.ping({
 requestTimeout: 300000,
}  , function(error) {
 if (error) {
     console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
 } else {
     console.log('Everything is ok');
 }
 });

//call createIndexOnES function. Note Index name must be small letters
await createIndexOnES(elasticSearchClient, 'testelastic');
}

//Function to create Index in AWS Elastic Search searvice
async function createIndexOnES (elasticSearchClient, indexName){
 await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 elasticSearchClient.create({
    index: indexName,
    type: '_doc',
    id: '1',
    body: {
        properties: { 
                      "field-1":{"type": "text"},
                      "field-2":{ "type": "text"},
                      "field-3":{"type": "integer"},
                      "field-4":{"type": "date"},
                      "field-5":{"type": "keyword"},

     }
    }
 }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error on creating data", err);
        // next(err);
    } else {
        console.log("data reply received", data);
        // next(null, true);
    }
});

});
}
```

**Output of Lambda Function:**

[image]